# Flask & nginx - i can't solve this error "no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---"

Tags: python, nginx, flask

i want to connect flask with nginx but i doesn't work...

here is my code

1. hello4.py

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   application = Flask(__name__)

   @application.route("/")
   def hello():
       return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
   ```
2. wsgi.py

   ```
   from hello4 import app as application

   if __name__=="__main__":
       application.run()
   ```

well, in here i changed part"app as application", "app", "application"...
but it dosen't work.

3. myproject.ini

   ```
   [uwsgi]
   chdir = /home/pi/myproject/hello4.py
   module = wsgi:app

   socket = myproject.sock
   chmod-socket = 666
   vacuum = true

   daemonize = /home/pi/myproject/uwsgi.log
   die-on-term = true
   ```
4. /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite

   ```
   server{
          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80 ipv6only default_server;
          server_name www.pizza.com;

          location / {try_files $uri @app; }
          location @app{
                   include uwsgi_params;
                   uwsgi_pass unix:/home/pi/myproject/myproject.sock;
          }
   }
   ```

myproject.sock is result of myproject.ini

here is my error code

---no python application found, check your startup logs for errors---
[pid: 2378|app: -1|req: -1/23] 127.0.0.1() {40 vars in 719 bytes} [Mon Mar 25 22: 47: 18 2019] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 swithes on core 0)

Comment: A couple of things stand out to me. I think `chdir` in the .ini file should point to the project directory not the `hello.py` module. Also the `module = wsgi:app` should be `module = wsgi:application` given that your app is imported in `wsgi.py` as `application`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it tomorrow morning!

Comment: Glad I could help!